# How do I get all the names in the "a" tags that are in one "div" tag for all the div tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the names in each html line and store all of them together if they are in the same line.
For example for the first line I would want [Finneas O'Connell, Rob Kinelski, John Greenhan] and the second one would be [Louis Bell, Frank Dukes, Manny Marroquin, Mike Bozzi] and so on.

```
[<a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/finneas-oconnell/251939" title="Click to view a local node.">Finneas O'Connell</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/rob-kinelski/251846" title="Click to view a local node.">Rob Kinelski</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/john-greenham/251779" title="Click to view a local node.">John Greenham</a>]
[<a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/louis-bell/243143" title="Click to view a local node.">Louis Bell</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/adam-feeney/18417" title="Click to view a local node.">Frank Dukes</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/manny-marroquin/14875" title="Click to view a local node.">Manny Marroquin</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/mike-bozzi/17767" title="Click to view a local node.">Mike Bozzi</a>]
[<a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/j-white-did-it/188876" title="Click to view a local node.">J. White Did It</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/eddie-%E2%80%9Cemix%E2%80%9D-hern%C3%A1ndez/298062" title="Click to view a local node.">Eddie “eMIX” Hernández</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/shawn-source-jarrett/298063" title="Click to view a local node.">Shawn "Source" Jarrett</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/jaycen-joshua/3518" title="Click to view a local node.">Jaycen Joshua</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/stuart-white/12821" title="Click to view a local node.">Stuart White</a>, <a class="freelink freelink-nid freelink-internal" href="/grammys/artists/colin-leonard/243375" title="Click to view a local node.">Colin Leonard</a>]
```

when I use the code below it just lists them all one by one for all of them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.grammy.com/grammys/awards/winners-nominees/138'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
category = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "view-grouping-content")

for i in category:
  
    workers = i.find_all('div', class_="views-field views-field-body-1")
    for f in workers:
        k = f.findAll('a')
      
        for a in k:
         print(a.string)
```

I am just confused on how I would fix this issue

Comment: You could add a print statement during each f in workers (might clear up some confusion - you have the names in groups). And as said, you may want to store data as well as print it out.

Comment: @Diego I believe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68631421/12446721) solves your issue. Please mark that as an answer if that solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get your expected output :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.grammy.com/grammys/awards/winners-nominees/138'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
category = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "view-grouping-content")

for i in category:
    for f in i.find_all('div', class_="views-field views-field-body-1"):
        k = f.findAll('a')
        x=[]
        for a in k:
            x.append(a.text)
        print(x)
```

We are just making new list `(x)` that stores all workers name, and printing them one by one.